# onClick() function is not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<html><br>
<head><br>
<title>fetch data from library records</title><br>
<script>     <br>
var request;<br>
function sendInfo()<br>
{<br>
alert("my name is rakesh:");<br>
document.getElementById("rakesh").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";<br>
var v1=document.myform.username.value;<br>
var v2=document.myform.password.value;<br>
var v3=document.myform.idate.value;<br>
var v4=document.myform.ddate.value;<br>

var url="index.jsp?val1="+v1+"&val2="+v2+"&val3="+v3+"&val4="+v4;<br>

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){<br>
request=new XMLHttpRequest();<br>
}<br>
else if(window.ActiveXObject){<br>
request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");<br>
}<br>
try<br>
{<br>
request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;<br>
request.open("GET",url,true);<br>
request.send();<br>
}<br>
catch(Exception e)<br>
{<br>
alert("Unable to connect to server");<br>
}<br>
}<br>
function getInfo(){<br>
if(request.readyState==4){<br>
var val=request.responseText;<br>
document.getElementById('rakesh').innerHTML=val;<br>
}<br>
} <br>
</script><br>
</head><br>
<body><br>
<form name="myform" id="mform"><br>
<table><br>
<tr><br>
<td>Enter UserName : </td><br>
<td><input type='text' name="username" id="username"/></td><br>
</tr><br>
<tr><br>
<td>Enter PassWord : </td><br>
<td><input type='password' name="password" id="password"/></td><br>
</tr><br>
<tr><br>
<td>Enter IssueDate: </td><br>
<td><input type='text' name="idate"/></td><br>
</tr><br>
<tr><br>
<td>Enter DepositDate:</td><br> 
<td><input type='text' name="ddate"/></td><br>
</tr><br>   
<tr><br>
<td><input type="button" name="sub" value="fetch" onClick="sendInfo()"></td><br>
</tr><br>
</table><br>
</form><br>
<span id="rakesh"></span><br>

</body><br>
</html><br>
```

Comment: Please consider improving the format of your code so others can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have modified your code.
Please check it out below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>fetch data from library records</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" id="mform">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter UserName : </td>
                    <td><input type='text' name="username" id="username"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter PassWord : </td>
                    <td><input type='password' name="password" id="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter IssueDate: </td>
                    <td><input type='text' name="idate"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter DepositDate:</td> 
                    <td><input type='text' name="ddate"/></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" name="sub" value="fetch" onclick="sendInfo()"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <span id="rakesh"></span>

    </body>

        <script type="text/javascript">     
            var request;
            function sendInfo()
            {
                alert("my name is rakesh:");
                document.getElementById("rakesh").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
                var v1=document.myform.username.value;
                var v2=document.myform.password.value;
                var v3=document.myform.idate.value;
                var v4=document.myform.ddate.value;

                var url="index.jsp?val1="+v1+"&val2="+v2+"&val3="+v3+"&val4="+v4;

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                try
                {
                    request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;
                    request.open("GET",url,true);
                    request.send();
                }                   

                catch(Exception)
                {
                    alert("Unable to connect to server");
                }
            }
            function getInfo(){
                if(request.readyState==4){
                    var val=request.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('rakesh').innerHTML=val;
                }
            } 
        </script>
</html>
```